# Grabbing data from Yahoo's API using JSON

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to fetch some data from Yahoo's API and Im running into some troubles.

Here is a snippet of Yahoo's JSON output

```
cbfunc({
 "query": {
  "count": 25,
  "created": "2012-03-10T07:49:06Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "diagnostics": {
   "publiclyCallable": "true",
   "url": {
    "execution-start-time": "2",
    "execution-stop-time": "364",
    "execution-time": "362",
    "content": "http://us.music.yahooapis.com/track/v1/list/search/track/Madonna?start=1&count=25"
   },
   "user-time": "369",
   "service-time": "362",
   "build-version": "25587"
  },
  "results": {
   "Track": [
    {
     "discNumber": "1",
     "duration": "0",
     "explicit": "0",
     "flags": "0",
     "id": "31884342",
     "label": "Touch and Go Records",
     "popularity": "3",
     "rating": "-1",
     "releaseYear": "2003",
     "rights": "160",
     "title": "Madonna",
     "trackNumber": "10",
     "url": "http://new.music.yahoo.com/cocorosie/tracks/madonna--31884342",
     "Artist": {
      "catzillaID": "1927768063",
      "flags": "57859",
      "hotzillaID": "1808720053",
      "id": "23301762",
      "name": "Cocorosie",
      "rating": "-1",
      "trackCount": "118",
      "url": "http://new.music.yahoo.com/cocorosie/",
      "website": "http://www.cocorosieland.com/"
     },
     "Album": {
      "Release": {
       "UPC": "036172095360",
       "explicit": "0",
       "flags": "2",
       "id": "31881255",
       "label": "Touch and Go Records",
       "rating": "-1",
       "releaseDate": "2003-09-20T07:00:00Z",
       "releaseYear": "2003",
       "rights": "160",
       "title": "La Maison De Mon Rêve",
       "typeID": "2",
       "url": "http://new.music.yahoo.com/cocorosie/albums/maison-de-mon-reve--31881255",
       "Image": [
        {
         "size": "40",
         "url": "http://d.yimg.com/ec/image/v1/release/31881255?size=40"
        },
        {
         "size": "65",
         "url": "http://d.yimg.com/ec/image/v1/release/31881255?size=65"
        },
        {
         "size": "75",
         "url": "http://d.yimg.com/ec/image/v1/release/31881255?size=75"
        },
        {
         "size": "80",
         "url": "http://d.yimg.com/ec/image/v1/release/31881255?size=80"
        },
        {
         "size": "110",
         "url": "http://d.yimg.com/ec/image/v1/release/31881255?size=110"
        },
        {
         "size": "135",
         "url": "http://d.yimg.com/ec/image/v1/release/31881255?size=135"
        },
        {
         "size": "200",
         "url": "http://d.yimg.com/ec/image/v1/release/31881255?size=200"
        },
        {
         "size": "300",
         "url": "http://d.yimg.com/ec/image/v1/release/31881255?size=300"
        },
        {
         "size": "654",
         "url": "http://d.yimg.com/ec/image/v1/release/31881255?size=654"
        },
        {
         "size": "800",
         "url": "http://d.yimg.com/ec/image/v1/release/31881255?size=800"
        }
       ]
      }
     },
```

The problem I am running into is I am only able to  data under "Tracks". I would like to retrieve more data. Data under "Album" and "Artist".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access it as

```
$Track->Artist->name
$Track->Album->Release->label
```

inside the foreach loop

Comment: Thanks. I tried that earlier and it didn't work. I guess I did something wrong. Its working now. Thanks!